# Placement of duration complement 很长时间 before a negated verb 没看?

Tags: grammar, usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, word-order

I found the following sentence:

> 我很长时间没看电影了。
>
> Wǒ hěn cháng shíjiān méi kàn diànyǐngle.
>
> I haven't watched a movie in a very long time.

I believe 很长时间 (very long time) is the duration of the action 没看 (haven't watched).

**Q1:** Why is it located before the verb when duration should go after the verb?

**Q2:** Does the final 了 indicate a change of status suggesting the speaker wants to watch a movie soon?

Comment: I just found out my answer to Q1, from Claudia Ross, Jing-heng Sheng Ma - Modern Mandarin Chinese Grammar:
*Indicating how long it has been that something has not occurred:*
*In Mandarin, only situations that occur can be described in terms of their duration. If a situation does not occur, the duration pattern cannot be used to describe it. To indicate the length of time that something has not occurred, put the time phrase before the [prepositional phrase +] verb or verb phrase.*

Comment: You can answer your own question below actually, instead placing it in a comment.

Comment: is 长 typically used in this way? I normally associate 久 with time durations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: Why is it located before the verb when duration should go after the verb?

The explanation you posted in your comment is correct. Reposting it here for clarity: when expressing the duration of an inaction, the duration complement goes before the verb, following the pattern:

*Duration + 没 + Verb + 了*

> Q2: Does the final 了 indicate a change of status suggesting the speaker wants to watch a movie soon?

No, it indicates the change of status that occurred when you started not doing something.

In your example, it's the change from watching movies to not watching movies.